# django's not working when implement a custom middleware to check whether user is active and check if user is login then it can be enter in the site

Tags: django

django's not working when implement a custom middleware to check whether user is active and check if user is login then it can be enter in the site otherwise it will back to the login page

my middleware is i just try to implement that for check if user is not login then it can not enter in to site

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
class FilterMiddleware(object):
    # Check if client is allowed
    def process_request(self, request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated() :
            form_class = AuthenticationForm
            template_name = 'music/login_form.html'
            form = form_class(None)
            return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
        return super(FilterMiddleware, self).dispatch(request)
```

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'music.middleware.filter_middleware.FilterMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'

]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use  @login_required decorator to redirect to login page if user is not loggedIn.